# displaying Multiple select option in diiferent line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multiple select option that display the result in a div container, when click on ctrl+"orange""apple""banana" the result display: "orange, apple, banana" in one line, but i want to display each result in a new single line with a link that goes to different page like this:

Orange - "goes to a link" 
Apple - "goes to a link" 
Banana - "goes to a link"

Here are my codes below:

```
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
<select name="" multiple="multiple" id="select-custom-19">    
    <option>Add Fruits</option>        
    <option value="orange" selected>orange</option> 
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>             </select>
<div style="width:300px; height:70px; background-color:#E1D903; 
        color:#000000; margin: 10px; "> <span id="yourfruit"> </span>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#select-custom-19').change(function() {
            /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
            var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            /* setting input box value to selected option value */
            $('#yourfruit').text($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think your code really answer my question but can i make it such a way that each fruit goes to a different link like: orange  - orange.html, banana - banana.html. instead of it linking to the same url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate throug items and display them, append an anchor (`<a />`) and use `<br />` for a new line.

Make sure to add `.empty()` to clean the fruits from list before `.append()` other items to `$('#yourfruit')`, like in example below.

```
var fruits = $(this).val();
$('#yourfruit').empty();
for (var fruit in fruits) {
   var label = $('<label/> ').text(fruits[fruit]+" - ");
   $('#yourfruit').append(label)
                   .append($('<a  class="tab-btn" />').text(fruits[fruit]).attr('href', fruits[fruit] + '.html'))
                  .append('<br />');
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select-custom-19').change(function() {
    /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    /* setting input box value to selected option value */
    var fruits = $(this).val();
    $('#yourfruit').empty();
    for (var fruit in fruits) {
        var label = $('<label/> ').text(fruits[fruit] + " - ");
        $('#yourfruit').append(label)
                       .append($('<a  class="tab-btn" />').text(fruits[fruit]).attr('href', fruits[fruit] + '.html'))
                       .append('<br />');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.tab-btn {
  color: red;
}
.tab-btn:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" multiple="multiple" id="select-custom-19">
  <option>Add Fruits</option>

  <option value="orange" selected>orange</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>

</select>

<div style="width:300px; height:70px; background-color:#E1D903; 
    color:#000000; margin: 10px; ">
  <span id="yourfruit"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think your code really answer my question but can i make it such a way that each fruit goes to a different link like: orange  - orange.html, banana - banana.html. instead of it linking to the same url

Comment: Hello, Am a lil bit novice with jquery, i am trying to style the result that display after selecting one or more options but didnt apply to all the result display from the option box, see below.  $('#yourfruit').append(label)
                  .append($('<a class="tab-btn" />').text(fruits[fruit]).attr('href', fruits[fruit] + '.html'))
                  .append('<br />');
    }

Comment: @JideIgun See my updated snnipet, this is what you try to achieve?, the code you showed me seems to work.

Comment: yes, the code does work partially, the css code i apply didn't work all through, see my css below.  .tab-btn{
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 list-style-type:none;
 height: 30px;
 line-height:30px;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #B4008C;
 background-color:#C8C8C8;}

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `<br/>` element after every selected option. I have used `<label>` element  but you can add link or any other element you want

```
$(document).ready( function ()
     {
     $('#select-custom-19').change(function(){

        $('#yourfruit').empty();

        var values = $(this).val();

        for(var i=0; i < values.length ; i++)
        {
          $('#yourfruit').append('<lable>'+values[i]+'</label><br/>');
        }   
      });
 });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqjwa93d/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select name="" multiple="multiple" id="select-custom-19">
  <option>Add Fruits</option>
  <option value="orange" selected>orange</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
<div style="width:300px; height:70px; background-color:#E1D903;  color:#000000; margin: 10px; ">
  <ul id="yourfruit">
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function ()
     {

           $('#select-custom-19').change(function()
           {
        /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        /* setting input box value to selected option value */
        $('#yourfruit').append('<li>'+$(this).val()+'</li>');
            }
              );
                 });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add `HTML` tags as per your requirements, like `<a>` or `</br>`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select-custom-19').change(function () {
        $('#yourfruit').text("");
        if($(this).val() != null)
        {
           $(this).val().forEach(function (value, index) {
               $('#yourfruit').append("<a href='#'>" + value + "</a></br>");
           });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" multiple="multiple" id="select-custom-19">
    <option>Add Fruits</option>
    <option value="orange" selected>orange</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
<div style="width:300px; height:70px; background-color:#E1D903; 
    color:#000000; margin: 10px; "> <span id="yourfruit"> </span>

</div>
```